# How can I disable auto-play blocking on a per-site basis?

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra

I would like to disable auto-play blocking, which was a feature introduced in macOS 10.13 High Sierra, the version I'm using, on one specific news site, and not every single website. Am I even allowed to do this?

Comment: Rather than asking a "yes/no" question, why not ask _how_ to customize and then get an answer that shows how to do this as opposed to asking for yes/no?

Comment: @bmike I did ask "How can I disable auto-play blocking on a per-site basis?".

Comment: @bmike I overhauled the answer. It has pictures, content, and multiple solutions.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, you can disable auto-play blocking on a per-site basis.**

Safari preferences have a panel in the "Websites" tab that has a list of auto-play blocking exclusions.

[image: Auto-play blocking exclusions list in Safari preferences]

Each website has its own listing if the auto-play settings have been changed manually using the "Settings for This Website..." popup. You can pick three options for auto-play blocking for each item separately:

- Allow All Auto-Play
- Stop Media with Sound
- Never Auto-Play

You can also choose to have a default option for websites not in the list. The options are the same 3 that can be changed in a listing. "Stop Media with Sound" is the default settings.

There seems to be no way of adding websites to the list via this interface, but you can remove each item using the 'Remove' button below the list.

In order to change a website's settings (and thus, add it to the list), you must right-click on the address and search bar while on the website you want to edit. Click the bottom option named "Settings for This Website..." and a pop-up with multiple settings, including auto-play blocking options, will appear.

[image: Webite settings popup in Safari]

You must hover on the value you want to change. If you click, the same list of options shown for the defaults preference will be shown, but it will only apply to that website.

1 is not picture with a listing! --->